# $_GET is not working in wp customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I am using `wp_footer` action to display a bar on top of site.

I used [`is_customize_preview()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_customize_preview/) and getting the bar id which is in url of customizer and it's not returning anything.

Below is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer',  'jws_ob_content');
function jws_ob_content() {
  if( is_customize_preview() ) {
      $offer = get_post( $_GET['offer_id'] );
      $offer_custom = get_post_custom( $_GET['offer_id'] );
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r( $_GET['offer_id'] );
      exit();
  }
  else {
      $offer = get_post('505');
      $offer_custom = get_post_custom('505');
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the method `is_customize_preview()` do?

Comment: is_customize_preview() return true if it is customizer.

Comment: Check `print_r($_REQUEST);` ?

Comment: vrajesh check the updated code

Comment: returns this 
    Array
(
    [page_id] => 519
    [customize_changeset_uuid] => 47cffcc9-3a55-4b35-887c-4e8497ff9da9
    [customize_theme] => twentyseventeen
    [customize_messenger_channel] => preview-0
)

Answer (score 0):

I encoded the url by [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and write &autofocus[panel]=something and the end of url and it's works fine.